# How to use model.predict in keras?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I am using keras `model.predict` after training my model for a sentence classification task. My code is

```
import numpy as np
model = Sequential()
l = ['Hello this is police department', 'hello this is 911 emergency']
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(l)
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(l)
X = np.array(X)
a = model.predict(X)
print(a)
```

But the output seems to be an array,

```
[[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [1. 2. 3. 6. 7.]]
```

I am working on a sentence classification task with 2 labels. So I wanted to predict these sentences as `0` or `1`. But instead getting a numpy array. How do I code such that it predicts one of these two labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add some layer to your model. to get probabilities in [0,1] use sigmoid as last activation

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

maxlen = 10

X_train = ['Hello this is police department', 
     'hello this is 911 emergency',
     'asdsa sadasd',
     'asnxas asxkx',
     'kas',
     'jwxxxx']
y_train = ['positive','negative','positive','negative','positive','negative']

label_enc = LabelEncoder()
label_enc.fit(y_train)

tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)

X_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
X_train = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=maxlen)

y_train = label_enc.transform(y_train)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(maxlen,)))
model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy')
model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=3)


### PREDICT NEW UNSEEN DATA ###

X_test = ['hello hSDAS', '911 oaoad']

X_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)
X_test = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=maxlen)

a = (model.predict(X_test)>0.5).astype(int).ravel()
print(a)

reverse_pred = label_enc.inverse_transform(a.ravel())
print(reverse_pred)
```

Comment: It is working, But suppose, I have emotion classification task and I want to rate it as `0` for negative and `1` for positive. How should I use the training/testing model so that it predicts according to that. Here in your example, it is just predicting `0` or `1` based on probabilities.

Comment: you can map 0 as nevative and 1 as positive. is this what u mean?

Comment: No no, see here in our example, we are predicting without any prior training/testing. So this is just plain prediction. What if I want to predict based on my trained sentences. Like in training I have trained my data and now I want to use that to predict newer sentences which are not in the dataset.

Comment: after fitting on train u have to use the same fitted model to do predictions. remember to operate the same preprocessing. I edited it with an example. don't forget to upvote and accept as answer ;-)