# LabelEncoder instance is not fitted yet

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, nlp

I have a code for prediction of unseen data in a sentence classification task.

The code is

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

maxlen = 1152

### PREDICT NEW UNSEEN DATA ###
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
label_enc = LabelEncoder()
X_test = ['this is boring', 'wow i like this you did a great job']

X_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=maxlen)

a = (model.predict(X_test)>0.5).astype(int).ravel()
print(a)

reverse_pred = label_enc.inverse_transform(a.ravel())
print(reverse_pred)
```

But I am getting this error

```
[1 1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFittedError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-7e12dbe8aec1> in <module>()
     39 print(a)
     40 
---> 41 reverse_pred = label_enc.inverse_transform(a.ravel())
     42 print(reverse_pred)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_is_fitted(estimator, attributes, msg, all_or_any)
    965 
    966     if not attrs:
--> 967         raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})
    968 
    969 

NotFittedError: This LabelEncoder instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

I have used Sequential model and the `model.fit` is written as `history=model.fit()` in the training part. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: u have to fit the encoder with some labels otherwise you can apply inverse_transform

Comment: Can you plz provide a snippet of code so that I can understand it better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

following the sklearn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) and what reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62995337/how-to-use-model-predict-in-keras), you have simply to fit your encoder before making an inverse transform

```
y = ['positive','negative','positive','negative','positive','negative']
label_enc = LabelEncoder()
label_enc.fit(y)

model_predictions = np.random.uniform(0,1, 3)
model_predictions = (model_predictions>0.5).astype(int).ravel()
model_predictions = label_enc.inverse_transform(model_predictions)
```

Comment: Just a doubt, will `y` contain all the labels I had used in the training part. Like, if my training part had 1000 sentences ancorresponding target labels for 1000 sentences, should I fit all those 1000 labels in `y`?

Comment: you can pass all the 1000 or simply one label for each types. I suggest you to pass all, the label encoder will do the rest